# Do Elite subcriptions give advantages?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Will the Elite subscription give an advantage to players who haven't subscribed?

I know you can participate in daily competitions to win real and virtual prizes. 
You'll have some free downloadable content (maps I guess, avatars...). Will it give you the opportunity to have new (not necessarily better) weapons, perks, or equipment, or bonuses like being able to create more classes or have more perks at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there appear to be no in-game advantages provided with the Call of Duty Elite Premium account. I would consider everything besides the DLC included with the Premium membership to be fluff (just my opinion), but definitely nothing that gives you a competitive advantage in-game with extra perks, weapons, etc.

The full list of what's included is [here](http://www.callofduty.com/elite/whats-included). The things that are listed as extras with Elite Premium:

- All DLC
- Daily Competitions
- Exclusive Clan Benefits (exclusive emblems and tags)
- Pro video guides and tactics (tutorials?)
- Premium Groups
- Early access to new features
- Upload HD videos
- Access to Call of Duty Elite TV.

All other features are accessible by free members, like stats, setting up your loadouts, etc.

Comment: I've heard that having an Elite Premium account gives you an extra prestige (so you go to 11th prestige). This is kind of an in-game advantage, but barely.