# What exactly does Elite Premium get you?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Elite subcriptions give advantages?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34634/do-elite-subcriptions-give-advantages)

Is it just future DLC or is there more features (on the web or in-game)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full list of what's included is [here](http://www.callofduty.com/elite/whats-included). The things that are listed as extras with Elite Premium and not included with the regular free account are:

- All future DLC
- Daily Competitions
- Exclusive Clan Benefits (exclusive emblems and tags)
- Pro video guides and tactics (tutorials?)
- Premium Groups
- Early access to new features
- Upload HD videos
- Access to Call of Duty Elite TV.

Also, I answered this in [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34634/do-elite-subcriptions-give-advantages), however the question was phrased differently.